# Why do these Gradle tests throw exceptions?

Tags: grails-orm, gradle

I've got following test

```
answer = Author.withCriteria {
            books {
                gt 'price', new DetachedCriteria(Book).build {
                    projections {
                        avg 'price'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

assert answer.size() == 1
```

Intellij IDEA executes this test without exceptions. If I run `gradle build` this test rises `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query` exception.

Intellij generates following SQL:
`select this_.id as id2_1_, this_.version as version2_1_, this_.age as age2_1_, this_.email as email2_1_, this_.first_name as first5_2_1_, this_.home_page as home6_2_1_, this_.last_name as last7_2_1_, this_.login as login2_1_, this_.salary as salary2_1_, this_.sex as sex2_1_, (SELECT count(*) FROM BOOK b WHERE b.author_id = this_.id) as formula0_1_, books_alia1_.id as id1_0_, books_alia1_.version as version1_0_, books_alia1_.author_id as author3_1_0_, books_alia1_.date_created as date4_1_0_, books_alia1_.last_updated as last5_1_0_, books_alia1_.price as price1_0_, books_alia1_.title as title1_0_ from author this_ inner join book books_alia1_ on this_.id=books_alia1_.author_id where (books_alia1_.price > (select avg(cast(this_.price as double)) as y0_ from book this_))`

Gradle SQL:
`select this_.id as id2_1_, this_.version as version2_1_, this_.age as age2_1_, this_.email as email2_1_, this_.first_name as first5_2_1_, this_.home_page as home6_2_1_, this_.last_name as last7_2_1_, this_.login as login2_1_, this_.salary as salary2_1_, this_.sex as sex2_1_, (SELECT count(*) FROM BOOK b WHERE b.author_id = this_.id) as formula0_1_, books_alia1_.id as id0_0_, books_alia1_.version as version0_0_, books_alia1_.author_id as author3_0_0_, books_alia1_.date_created as date4_0_0_, books_alia1_.last_updated as last5_0_0_, books_alia1_.price as price0_0_, books_alia1_.title as title0_0_ from author this_ inner join book books_alia1_ on this_.id=books_alia1_.author_id where (books_alia1_.price > (select  from book this_)`

You can see problems with `avg 'price'` part.

Question is the same: Why tests executed by Gradle have exceptions?

ps
Intellij dependecies are installed by `gradle idea` command

Answer (score 0):

Only you can find out. Maybe the class paths are different (remember that IDEA doesn't have as strict a class path separation as Gradle), or the resources are different (again this works differently in IDEA compared to Gradle). First thing to do is to analyze the stack trace. Debugging the test in Gradle (`-Dtest.debug=true`) can also help.